# C# Problem with HasAttributes and xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with the HasAttribute. It always returns false, but I want 1 returned, when it did finded element with attribute "ignore-it". Ex: Sum elemnents, ignore those elements with "ignore-it" as attribute or in element "ignore-it".

**Code:**

```
using System.Xml;

namespace ReadFileXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("data.xml");
            int sum = 0;
            int scanOrNo = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "number" )
                {
                    string a = "NULL";
                    string s1 = reader.ReadElementString();
                    if(reader.HasAttributes)
                        a = reader.GetAttribute("ignore-it");
                    Console.WriteLine("string:" + a);
                    if (scanOrNo % 2 == 0 && a  != "true" )

                        sum += int.Parse(s1);

                    Console.WriteLine(s1);
                }
                else if (reader.Name == "ignore-it")
                {
                    scanOrNo += 1;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("sum = "+sum);       
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<numbers>
    <number ignore-it="true">1</number>
    <number>2</number>
    <number>3</number>
    <number ignore-it="true">4</number>
    <ignore-it>
        <number>100</number>
        <number>200</number>
        <number>300</number>
        <number>400</number>
    </ignore-it>
    <number>5</number>
</numbers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ReadElementString` before `reader.HasAttributes` erase the property value, if you call it after `reader.HasAttributes` will work well.

I have changed little your code:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "number")
    {
        string a = "NULL";
        if (reader.HasAttributes)
            a = reader.GetAttribute("ignore-it");

        Console.WriteLine("string:" + a);

        string s1 = reader.ReadElementString();
        if (scanOrNo % 2 == 0 && a != "true")
            sum += int.Parse(s1);

        Console.WriteLine(s1);
    }
    else if (reader.Name == "ignore-it")
    {
        scanOrNo += 1;
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
sum = 10
```

i hope this help you out.

Comment: Yes,I have. Thanks for your time, but why is it working like that and ReadElementString() erase value of HasAttributes

Comment: honestly i don't know why, but Microsoft recommend ``ReadElementContentAsString`` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementstring?view=netframework-4.8 instead ``ReadElementString``, i'm making some search but i don't find any answer. if you find anything please share it with me.

Comment: I've tried using `ReadElementContentAsString` in old place ReadElementString, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: yeah, i tried it too. but it's not work in the old place.